# iOS - Swift - Compare 2 entities for the values

Tags: ios, swift

I need to compare the values in one Entity another entity. 
I donot want to have the one on one string comparison.
As it has so many Params, and the values will be keep adding in future.
Do we have any simple solution for this?

Its not about Core Data. Normal Custom Objects.

For Ex:  I need to compare to Employee Object for its values.

Answer (score 1):

```
func compareTwoEntities() -> Bool
{
    let json = JSONSerializer.toJson(userEntity)

    let json2 = JSONSerializer.toJson(userBackUpEntity)


    if json == json2
    {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try comparing two arrays made of these elements of entities. Have you tried that?

Comment: Can you please give me an example?